# What event is simiar to dblclick on mobile?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to simulate the dblclick event on the device but I couldn't find a method that could be similar to this one, is there any way?

```js
window.ontouchstart = (e) => {
console.log("1");
  if (e.detail == 2)
  console.log("2");
}
```

Comment: Maybe the browser already does fire `dblclick` when double-tapping? If not, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events

Comment: On devices with touchs dblclick doesn't work, and I've tried `event.touches.length 2` but it doesn't work either